# Presenting ViewController over current context gets stuck

Tags: ios, swift, uimodalpresentationstyle, uimodaltransitionstyle, touch-up-inside

I'm trying to present a viewcontroller modally over current context when I press a button ("Touch Down") and when I release that button ("Touch Up Inside") I want the viewcontroller to be dismissed.

This is my code: (buttonPressed is the "Touch Down" event and buttonReleased is the "Touch Up Inside" event)

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
    let anotherView = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AnotherView")
    anotherView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    anotherView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.crossDissolve
    present(anotherView, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


@IBAction func buttonReleased(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But if I spam the button anotherView gets stuck and leaves me there. Does anyone know a solution to this problem? Thank you.

**EDIT:** also, if I change the animation to false this still happens so it's probably not the issue.

**EDIT 2** I solved the problem. I was simply listening to the wrong event from the button. If you press and release the button really quickly it seems that the event that gets fired is "Touch Cancel". I added that as well and my code is now working as it should.

Comment: What you mean by spam the button.

Comment: Press it very frequently

Comment: You can disable the button in `viewWillDisappear` and enable it in `viewDidAppear` if you don't need that frequent events to be handled

Comment: @alexburtnik it was a nice idea but it did unfortunately not solve the problem. I also noticed the problem comes when I "flick" the button really quickly.

Comment: @nullforlife That's weird. Are you sure you didn't messed `viewWillDisappear` with `viewDidDisappear` or something like that?

Comment: @alexburtnik yes, but I also just noticed they don't even get called. Maybe they don't get called when you present a viewcontroller over current context?

Comment: Why are you creating a storyboard manually? Why don't you just call `self.storyboard`?

Comment: @nullforlife No, they should be called when you present modally. Perhaps you're overriding those methods in a subclass and not calling super? Can't imagine another reason for lifecycle methods not being called :)

Comment: @GuyKogus good question. I changed that now.

Comment: @alexburtnik Are you talking about anotherView's viewWillDisappear and viewWillAppear now or the 'initial' view controller?

Comment: @nullforlife Initial, since the button you need to disable is in your initial controller. Btw, anotherView is in fact a controller, don't mix them up ;)

Comment: @alexburtnik yes exactly, that's what I thought. Just wanted to be sure. They are not called anyway though...

Comment: @alexburtnik http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474034/view-controller-lifecycle-on-uimodalpresentationovercurrentcontext